# Extract table name from schema and table name

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the table name from a string that is in the format:

> [schemaname].[tablename]

I think this can be done with split but not sure how to handle the trailing ] character.

Comment: Split by dot and replace []. Or get with substring the last part and replace

Comment: a regex might be better.

Comment: be very careful! one probable scenario you might find is `[myDatabase].[mySchema].[tableName]` and `[myDatabase]..[tableName]` (yes, `..`, meaning default schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//find the seperator
var pos = str.IndexOf('].[');
if (pos == -1)
    return null; //sorry, can't be found.

//copy everything from the find position, but ignore ].[
// and also ignore the last ]
var tableName = str.Substr(pos + 3, str.Length - pos - 4);
```

Comment: @Sinatr: what about `schemaname.tablename` which is valid in sql

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You could go just for the dot and trim the square brackets after the substring. It could also be part of a larger string where the brackets or the dot appears in multiple places. But as we don't know that we'll answer using the constraints specified in the question.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is using `String.Split` and `String.Trim` in this little LINQ query:

```
string input = "[schemaname].[tablename]";
string[] schemaAndTable = input.Split('.')
    .Select(t => t.Trim('[', ']'))
    .ToArray();

string schema = schemaAndTable[0];
string table  = schemaAndTable[1];
```

Another one using `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
int pointIndex = input.IndexOf('.');
if(pointIndex >= 0)
{
    string schema = input.Substring(0, pointIndex).Trim('[', ']');
    string table  = input.Substring(pointIndex + 1).Trim('[', ']');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be the different here is another version with regex;

```
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\.\[)\w+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = input.Split('.')[1].Trim('[', ']');
```

Another LINQ solution:

```
var tableName = String.Join("", input.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1)
                                     .Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by 3 characters. i.e `[.]` with option `RemoveEmptyEntries` that is pretty self explanatory.

```
var result = input.Split(new [] {'[','.',']'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tableAndSchema = "[schemaname].[tablename]";
var tableName = tableAndSchema
    .Split('.')[1]
    .TrimStart('[')
    .TrimEnd(']');
```

`Split` will split the string on the `.` character and turn it into an array of two strings:

```
[0] = "[schemaname]"
[1] = "[tablename]"
```

The second (index 1) element is the one you want. `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` will remove the starting and ending brackets.

---

Another way to do this is with Regular Expressions:

```
var tableAndSchema = "[schemaname].[tablename]";
var regex = new Regex(@"\[.*\].\[(.*)\]");
var tableName = regex.Match(tableAndSchema).Groups[1];
```

The regex pattern `\[.*\].\[(.*)\]` creates a capture group for the characters within the second pair of brackets and lets you easily pull them out.